# View full (non-truncated) diagnostic error

Tags: plugin-coc, lsp

I am using coc.nvim to get "intellisense" on my project.

The diagnostic warnings & errors are great. However, sometimes those error messages are quite long, but the coc diagnostics message boxes have a fixed height and width, and hence truncate the full message.

[image]

How do I view the full error message within vim?

I've tried creating a new key mapping but it doesn't seem to have done anything:

```
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-info)
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagnostics warning is just a regular vim window!!!! All window tabbing / navigation controls apply to the coc diagnostics window!

You can tab into it by doing `CTRL+W` and then `W`.